# Django mutliple same GET parameter names not working

Tags: python, html, django

I have this simple Django form for filtering data with `GET` form:

```
from reservations.models import Reservation, ServiceType
from django import forms


PAYMENT_OPTIONS = (
    ('CASH', 'Cash'),
    ('ROOM', 'Charge to room'),
    ('ACCOUNT', 'Account'),
    ('VISA', 'Visa'),
    ('MASTERCARD', 'Mastercard'),
    ('AMEX', 'Amex'))

class FilterForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FilterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['service_date_from'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'datepicker'
        self.fields['service_date_to'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'datepicker'

    service_date_from = forms.CharField()
    service_date_to = forms.CharField()
    payment_options = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
                                         choices=PAYMENT_OPTIONS)
```

And then in the template:

```
<fieldset>
    <label>{{form.payment_options.label}}</label>
    {{form.payment_options}}
</fieldset>
```

The HTML:

```
<fieldset>
   <label>Payment options</label>
   <ul id="id_payment_options">
      <li><label for="id_payment_options_0"><input id="id_payment_options_0" name="payment_options" type="checkbox" value="CASH"> Cash</label></li>
      <li><label for="id_payment_options_1"><input id="id_payment_options_1" name="payment_options" type="checkbox" value="ROOM"> Charge to room</label></li>
      <li><label for="id_payment_options_2"><input id="id_payment_options_2" name="payment_options" type="checkbox" value="ACCOUNT"> Account</label></li>
      <li><label for="id_payment_options_3"><input id="id_payment_options_3" name="payment_options" type="checkbox" value="VISA"> Visa</label></li>
      <li><label for="id_payment_options_4"><input id="id_payment_options_4" name="payment_options" type="checkbox" value="MASTERCARD"> Mastercard</label></li>
      <li><label for="id_payment_options_5"><input id="id_payment_options_5" name="payment_options" type="checkbox" value="AMEX"> Amex</label></li>
   </ul>
</fieldset>
```

The problem is, when I select two or more payment options, I only get the last one in the url.

So for example, when I select Cash and Account, I'd get something like `?payment_options=ACCOUNT` and not `?payment_options=CASH&payment_options=ACCOUNT`

How can I fix that? I'm thinking that `payment_options` should be `payment_options[]` but don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `PAYMENT_OPTIONS` choice array is OK.

This is how I have it getting the payment options directly from the Model

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

self.fields['payments'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
                                queryset=Payment.objects.all(),
                                required=True,
                                error_messages = {'required': 'Payment Options is Required!'},
                                label='Payment Types',
                                widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={
                                  'class': 'checkbox-inline',}))
```

Please note the `ModelForm`

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
```

and also the `ModelMultipleChoiceField`

```
self.fields['payments'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
```

please also note that I'm using `POST` method to save the results.